# Change event on file-upload dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, events, file-upload, dialog

I am working with angular and trying to upload images to my database via a 'Image Upload' button that opens a file dialogue. For that purpose I want to be able to add several images with this button before eventually uploading them.

My button looks like this:

```
  <div class="file-managment">
    <button class="mat-raised-button custButt" style="margin: 5px;">Upload Images
      <label class="hiddenDialog">
        <input #file (change)="handleFile($event)" accept="image/*" type="file" multiple="multiple">
      </label>
    </button>
    <button class="mat-raised-button custButt" style="margin: 5px;">Delete Images</button>   </div>
```

In the `handleFile($event)` function I simply add the file from the dialogue to a list.

```
handleFile(event) {
  this.fileToUpload = event.target.files;
  this.uploadImages.append(this.fileToUpload.name, this.fileToUpload);
  console.log('added an element');
}
```

However, when I use the upload button multiple times to upload mutliple files, I notice that the `handleFile($event)` function is only called once. I using the (change) event wrong in this case? How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you trying to upload the same file(s) multiple times? If so then the change event would not occur. You could also try setting the value of the input to null after selecting the file for upload, it should cause the change event to trigger again

Comment: I've just tried to upload the same file multiple times and the change event is firing all time: try this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inttyl-angular-material-demo-vg1ntd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @HDJEMAI does not work for me, it only fires once (using Chrome)